# is it alright to define a global variable and initialize it there itself?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I use a global variable (an object of a class) and define it as follows:

```
//foo.h
extern class_name obj_name;
//foo.cpp
class_name obj_name("directory of a .ttf file");
```

I included foo.h in my main.cpp where my main() function resides.

The problem is that I am not very comfortable with initializing it there , since it is not inside a function. It's out in the open. I would have preferred calling an "init()" function that initializes the object like:

```
object_name = class_name(parameters);
```

from the main() function.

But the class is a 3rd party one and it doesn't accept objects being created without us providing parameters for the constructor. Maybe it doesn't have a default no-parameter constructor.

Is it good coding style to do what I did above?

Comment: You're already getting two different sets of answers: (1) "is it good coding style to use a globally-accessible object", (2) "given that you are going to use a globally-accessible object, is it good coding style for it to be defined with an initializer in namespace scope". If you're only interested in the answers to one of those questions, best say now before you're hip deep in answers to the other one.

Comment: actually I'd want answers to both questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Don't use globals in C++ without very good reason.

- You'll run into the "static initialisation order fiasco".
- You'll get ugly spaghetti code.
- Your code will be difficult to test.

This is especially true if your global is of a 3rd party type.

Consider using something nicer like a factory method allowing lazy initialization.
Or just pass the object around to functions that need it.

Also consider wrapping that 3rd party class with your own - only providing the minimal interfaces needed to test it, and use a pointer to that abstract base class. (Or if the 3rd party library supports it - use the most minimal interface they provide that you can get away with using)

Comment: Is the one written by jrok a "factory method" ?

Answer (score 3):

[Construct on first use idiom](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.15) can save you some worries:

```
// foo.h

class_name& get_obj();

// foo.cpp

class_name& get_obj()
{
    static class_name obj("dir");
    return obj;
}
```

[Another link.](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Construct_On_First_Use)

Comment: Okay, though I don't see any global variable, is this method equivalent to that of using a global variable ? (since the same address is accessible throughout the program).

Answer (score 1):

Global variables are almost always bad. However, provided you don't have another options (do you?) I would recomment to use a pointer. This way you can define the global pointer wherever you want, and initialize it in main or in any other function with operator new. However, this makes you responsible for deleting the object manually.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is not a good coding style.
BUT not all 3ed party apis are created "the right way" so there are situations when you will bend the rules. If you do that you can at least *comment it rigourosly* so you will know in the future why you did that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could help:

```
class ObjectFactory 
{
public:
    static class_name* getObject() 
    {
        if( ptr ) 
            return ptr;
        else
        {
            ptr = new class_name( <args> );
            return ptr;
        }                
    }

private:
    static class_name* ptr;

    ObjectFactory() : ptr(NULL) {}
}
```

Everytime you need to use the object you can just always do:

```
class_name *p = ObjectFactory::getObject();
```